# For online play what are the benefits of reloading your stack below a certain limit

Tags: online, bankroll-management

On some sites, you can automatically reload your stack once it gets below a certain limit. I can see why this might be beneficial for your table image so you're not seen as short stacked, but surely this benefit is outweighed by the fact that it is harder to track your bankroll.

What are your views on this practice?

Comment: if you are using a short stack strategy, then keep it to a short stack. if you are using a middle stack strategy, ... ... thanks

Answer (score 3):

Reloading to the max enables you to win the max possible amount from other players. If you think you have an edge over others at the table, you should be happy to have the largest possible amount of chips in front of you. When you first sit at a table or whenever you sink below that max buy-in threshold, you should want to top off your stack.

On the other hand, if you're less comfortable with post-flop play, you might want to play slightly short, so you have easier decisions (often shove vs fold decisions).

As for your comment about tracking your bankroll... you should be using PokerTracker or similar manager software. It will track all your hands in real-time on most online sites, so there's no problem with topping off as often as needed.

Comment: +1. In addition, it should be noted that a full stack makes full use of implied odds as well. About tracking, one can use also the free [FPDB](http://fpdb.wikidot.com/). There are also sites like [Pokerlabs](http://pokerprolabs.com/) that gives you extreme details.